# Suffix incrementally by group in a vector

Tags: r

Hi suppose I have a vector as such:

```
v <- c( "k", "k", "c", "c", "k", "c")
#I can suffix this by doing a paste
paste0 (v,"1")
"k1" "k1" "c1" "c1" "k1" "c1"
```

However is there a way to to incrementally add one to each of the group? 
What I want is the below without looping.

```
"k1" "k2" "c1" "c2" "k3" "c3"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use base R `ave` with `seq_along` to calculate occurence of each unique value in `v` and `paste` it as suffix.

```
ave(v, v, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, seq_along(x)))
#[1] "k1" "k2" "c1" "c2" "k3" "c3"
```

---

Or a bit more compact :

```
paste0(v, ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along))
#[1] "k1" "k2" "c1" "c2" "k3" "c3"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `make.unique` which will increment for each duplicated element

```
make.unique(v, sep="")
#[1] "k"  "k1" "c"  "c1" "k2" "c2"
```